# Show the last object with some condition Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails I want to put a link in the view to the last object with some condition, I know how to found the object, like this code

```
Equipment.where(name: "Bulldozer").last
```

But I don´t know the right syntax to put in the href to go to the show of the last Equipment with name Bulldozer

```
<td> <a href="<% link_to Equipment... %>"> text </a> </td>
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're almost there, you need to assign the object to an instance variable, it'll be available within the view. So, in the controller action:

```
@equipment = Equipment.where(name: "Bulldozer").last
```

then, in your view:

```
<td> 
  <%= link_to "text", equipment_path(@equipment) %>
</td>
```

`link_to` helper will generate the `<a>` tag for you